PVE: LVM initializes using wrong backend devices (non-multipathed components of a multipath device)
I have a server which runs Proxmox VE 8.2 (based on Debian 12), fully updated, which uses multipath SAN. There we have a space allocated, ten devices of 2T each, which are seen 16 times each (the number of paths) and which are mapped into 10 multipathed virtual devices and collected into a single LVM group, where a logical volume is carved. No problems on this part.
It was initialized "on the fly" and running all right, until the host was rebooted. After that I noticed that whenever one runs any LVM-related command (lvs, etc.) in the system shell, it emits the warning in the form:
WARNING: Device mismatch detected for <LV> which is accessing <list of devices like
 /dev/sdak, /dev/sdaz, /dev/sdbn, ...> instead of <list of the devices
 like /dev/mapper/oamdwhdg-01, /dev/mapper/oamdwhdg-02, ...>

These /dev/mapper/oamdwhdg-XX are in reality the multipath devices, they were named that way for operational reasons in /etc/multipath.conf:
multipaths {
...
    multipath {
        wwid 36...
        alias oamdwhdg-04
    }
...
}

I.e. for whatever reason, the LV is mapped using backend devices, instead of using multipath virtual devices.
So I updated the filter in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf, which now looks like this:
global_filter=[ "a|/dev/sda3|", "a|/dev/mapper/oamdwhdg|", "r|.*|" ]

(I updated it, not added, it was global_filter=["r|/dev/zd.*|","r|/dev/rbd.*|"] before with the comment added by pve-manager to avoid scanning ZFS zvols and Ceph rbds. I believe my filter is much more strict than this one.)
/dev/sda3 is the local disk where PVE is installed and it contains the VG pve which doesn't depend on SAN, so it is the only /dev/sd... which is not using multipath and it was whitelisted.
I tested this filter using vgscan and it shows both groups to be found.
Then I executed update-initramfs and rebooted. During boot, server failed into emergency shell. When I hit Ctrl+D there, it, however, booted almost normally: the multipathed VG is seen but not activated (as if vgchange -an oamdwhdg was not yet run). But then I activated it by hand perfectly normally with the said command and it worked flawlessly.

I suspect this is because multipath isn't correctly initialized before LVM in the initramfs, so it tried to set up mappings using /dev/sdXX devices. But why it failed to emergency shell when I added the filter I don't understand.
Two (very related) questions here: why emergency shell a.k.a. what is wrong and how to make it work as expected?

if this is a production environment, open up a ticket on the vendor. the max support costs around about 1k per year per physical cpu

I won't be able to have a budget for this, unfortunately :(

https://www.proxmox.com/en/proxmox-virtual-environment/pricing did you tried it?

I work with Proxmox for long time (like 10 years, since v2.3), and I had used subscriptions previously in another organization. You need not tell me how to buy it or something like that ;) I don't work there anymore and I don't have a budget for it here right now. // Also, back to technical, I used this kind of a setup, e.g. multipathed devices with LVM in a cluster, and the devices were given non-default names too, and there were no such problems...

It turned out to be very silly problem. I need no custom filters. I needed to have the proper multipath inclusion into initramfs, which multipath-tools alone doesn't do.
For that, there's a separate package multipath-tools-boot in Debian-based systems. It made dm-multipath modules and configuration from /etc to appear inside initramfs.
I removed all the custom changes to lvm.conf and run:
apt install multipath-tools-boot

Reboot, and voila, everything came up in the right state.
Important: after any changes to the multipath configuration or adding devices or whatever that changes /etc/multipath/wwids or /etc/multipath.conf, one needs to rebuild the initramfs to include updated versions:
update-initramfs -uk all

